# Is it legal or normal for a professor to require 65 or above on both assessments to pass the unit?

Tags: professorship, exams, syllabus

Our grades for the Coding class I am taking are divided between projects and exams. The professor I take the class under has the following policy on her syllabus:

If our cumulative average for either our exams or projects is below 65% we receive an F in the class.

For example, lets say your class grade was an 75% (C) with a 90% average for projects, but a 60% average for exams. You would receive a failing grade. To me this seems highly immoral considering some students simply aren't good test takers.

Just curious, but is this policy legal in any way?

Comment: Legal or not depends on your jurisdiction. Ethically, I would say that this is okay. Getting an average of 65% or *anything* (exams, projects, etc.) over the course of the semester shows that you lack understanding of the subject matter, and should repeat the course.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I disagree, in the UK a 65% corresponds to a mid 2:1, and would be considered a fairly good grade (70%+ is a 1st, the highest possible grade).

Comment: @astronat true; I'm not familiar with the UK system. Whatever standard is being used, being on the lower spectrum of that scale means that you don't understand the material well enough.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice It assumes a lack of understanding assuming reasonable grading.  I ended up dropping a class once with a 51% on the homework--not because I didn't understand it but because I had a very hard time figuring out how to show enough work to make the teacher happy.  I was constantly being dinged for the right answer but failing to show "work" where there wasn't really any to my mind--by the time the equation was written down I knew the answer to it.

Comment: @astronat I think it's safe to assume in this context that the highest possible (numeric) grade is 100%, and the highest possible (letter) grade is an "A", which kicks in at 90%+?  After all, 75% is indicated as a "C", which is consistent with U.S. style grading; under which a 65% (or below) is _never_ considered "fairly good".

Comment: @LorenPechtel: as a maths teacher, I couldn't care less about the answer of an equation (if you mean by that the numerical solution). What I care about is how you found it, if you found all solutions, or if your solutions are really solutions and not "extraneous" solutions.

Comment: @Taladris This was a physics class.  I don't mind a **reasonable** show work requirement but he was requiring "work" from 5 years lower down the math spectrum.  At the point I dropped I had a 67 on the one test--4th highest in the class of 120.  I actually had about a 97, it's just that when I got to the end of the third problem I saw my answer was "wrong"--tried again, same, tried a different approach.  In reality the problem was insolvable, my original answer was "correct."

Comment: Assuming a 90-80-70 grading scale (65% would be considered failing), the professor states that failing either projects or tests yields failing grade for the class. Under that rubric, you must decide based upon your test and project ability and experience whether to persevere or withdraw. Earn a 90 on both and avoid the problem.

Comment: I don't understand this question. If the professor asks the students to do something illegal, then your question makes sense. But, the policy says 65% means failure and you ask if it is legal? I am scratching my head and try to figure out what's happening?

Comment: 65% would be a pass with safe margin in every course and university I've ever seen. Unless the first 50% is purely revision, giving no recognition to half the knowledge in the syllabus is farcical.

Comment: @Nij I can only assume you haven't spent much time in North America. When the top grade doesn't kick in until 90% (or even 95%), students expect to be able to get every single mark without too much difficulty. So 65% could potentially be more like only knowing 3/4 of the minimal learning outcomes.

Comment: 90% is the boundary for top grades here. 50% is considered a bare pass and may be considered insufficient to advance the next level up. The top grade shouldn't kick in until quite high up; it doesn't follow that the lowest grade above a fail should also be very high up as well, unless the majority of the grade is just easy amd/or prior knowledge. In which case, why bother testing and/or grading it again, when the entry requirements mean they have it already?

Comment: Whether 65% are pass or fail obviously depends on how hard the exams are..

Comment: Only if you don't think about the difficulty of questions prior to using them. "Oops, I screwed them by asking grad-level work of a first-year, better just give A+ to anybody who didn't surrender immediately". Set an exam that tests the entirety of knowledge as deeply as possible, and then make the marks absolute. Someone who knows 8% of the content and can think through 80% of the work, shouldn't get 99% because everybody else was bad, or a 69% because everybody else was amazing.

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't seem too unusual to me, and I don't think very many people will share your view that it is "immoral".

At least in US universities, the professor has quite wide discretion to determine the grading policy, so long as it is clearly described in the syllabus and applied equally to all students.  This seems well within the realm of acceptability.  Schemes based on some weighted average of assignments and exams are the most common, but I've certainly seen schemes where you have to have a minimum grade on certain components to pass.

As far as "legal", laws tend to avoid micromanaging academic matters, so I would be very surprised if there is any law that would forbid this.  University policy is more likely to address it, but again, I'd be surprised if what you describe wasn't allowed.  I don't think you will have any success trying to fight this at a higher level.

As far as it being unfair to students who are poor test takers, bear in mind that in many educational systems, it is common for the course grade to be determined *entirely* by a single exam.  Rightly or wrongly, there's a long history of evaluating students by exams, with the attitude that students who aren't good at taking tests need to find a way to get better at it.  (Accommodations may be made for students whose test-taking difficulties are due to a diagnosed learning disability, but this usually means adjusting the exam conditions rather than de-emphasizing exams in general.)

You are certainly free to express your disagreement with this policy, either directly to the professor or in anonymous evaluations, but it may not be possible for her to change it after the course has started.  This could be seen as unfair to students who have been setting their priorities accordingly.

Comment: Odd question: If someone argued against the commonality/history of course grades being determined by final exams, to what reference could we direct them?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins The UK Unistats website shows the weighting of different types of assessment for every subject at every university, each year (I think). That would show there are many places/subjects where exams make up a large component of the mark.

Comment: @JessicaB: Thank you for that! Anyone have a reference for U.S.-based schools on that point?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the exam and the projects are intended to test *different* skills. So, it is only reasonable that a student has to pass both to pass the course. This is common practice at most courses in my department (in the Netherlands).

When I design a course, I have to specify the 'learning goals' and I have to explicitly state where and how I test them. My course might have five learning goals, three out of which are tested in an exam and two in some project work. As passing the course means that I testify you achieved all learning goals, it means that you have to pass both, and you cannot compensate a fail on one part with a good grade on the other. Therefore, in my view, the professor is doing the right thing.

Whether 65% is the right cutoff value probably depends a lot on the context, which is why we cannot judge that (see also the comments to your question).

Answer (score 2):

"Legal" is a very specific thing - and there's almost certainly no law governing how university professors in your area grade. So I would abandon the notion of *legal* right now.

Now, *is it a good idea*? There are arguments that could be made both ways - as you've noted, some students might not be good test takers, but on the other hand, failing any particular aspect of a course betrays a lack of mastery of the subject. This also prevents people with "good enough" scores to blow things off that won't harm their average much but might lower their score in a particular facet.

When it comes down to it though, professors have a *massive* amount of leeway in how they grade courses.

Comment: How much leeway is *also* highly dependent on context. There is a great deal in North America, but much less in the UK. Close to none in at least some institutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious way to stop students gaming the marking system, by only doing half the work for the course but still getting a pass grade.

It is a common practice outside academia for professional qualifications (e.g. accountancy) - why would you want to call somebody a "professional" if they aren't at least competent (even if not experts) in *all* the aspects of their profession?

Of course some people might take the view that anything which prevents *every* student from getting a degree is "immoral" - but I'm not one of them. If you take that to its logical conclusion, just issue everybody with a degree certificate when their birth is registered, and save all the time and money that is currently wasted on building schools, paying teachers, etc!